# Golang microservice middleware allow any type but be strict on endpoint

Tags: go

New to golang but what I'm trying to do is make my logging middleware generic e.g. allow any type and then call the method for the next layer.

So below us the loggingmiddleware package, where I want to be able to accept any type and print it out.

```
package loggingmiddleware

import (
    "context"
    "time"

    gokitlogger "github.com/go-kit/kit/log"
)

type layer interface {
    Run(context.Context, interface{}) (interface{}, error)
}

type LoggingMiddleware struct {
    Logger gokitlogger.Logger
    Layer  layer
}

func (mw LoggingMiddleware) Run(ctx context.Context, i interface{}) (output interface{}, err error) {

    defer func(begin time.Time) {

        mw.Logger.Log(
            "method", "name of method",
            "input", i,
            "output", output,
            "err", err,
            "took", time.Since(begin),
        )

    }(time.Now())

    output, err = mw.Layer.Run(ctx, i)
    return

}
```

However I want to be strict when calling the next method, if it needs to be string I want to set the type to be string rather than `interface{}`

In my example I want to make sure only a float64 type will be used as an argument

```
type mathServiceInterface interface {
    Run(context.Context, float64) (float64, error)
}

type mathService struct{}

func (mathService) Run(_ context.Context, f float64) (float64, error) {
    return f * f, nil
}
```

However with my current implementation I'm getting this error...

```
# github.com/jakelacey2012/blankit/blankit-ms/sqaure

./main.go:92: cannot use ms (type mathServiceInterface) as type loggingmiddleware.layer in field value:
        mathServiceInterface does not implement loggingmiddleware.layer (wrong type for Run method)
                have Run(context.Context, float64) (float64, error)
                want Run(context.Context, interface {}) (interface {}, error)

./main.go:92: cannot use loggingmiddleware.LoggingMiddleware literal (type loggingmiddleware.LoggingMiddleware) as type mathServiceInterface in assignment:
        loggingmiddleware.LoggingMiddleware does not implement mathServiceInterface (wrong type for Run method)
                have Run(context.Context, interface {}) (interface {}, error)
                want Run(context.Context, float64) (float64, error)
```

I understand the error, however I don't know whether my implementation is over complicating things because I don't know go.

I hope what I'm saying makes sense, I was unsure what to title this as so please feel free to edit it.

Also if you need more code to better explain please do let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's going to be calling these? At some point there is an actual consumer, and that consumer will (presumably, based on your code) be using an interface (either `layer` or an identical interface). If there's middleware, that interface will *necessarily be as generic as the middleware* - i.e., taking a `interface{}` as a parameter to `Run`. So making something downstream more specific (besides not compiling as you've seen) doesn't make any sense: the actual consumer won't see the more-specific interface, it will see `Run(Context,interface{}) (interface{},error)`.

Comment: Okay I think I'm following what you are saying, which is if I'm going to be specific I need to do it in the middlware also. and if I am then I need to create a different logger middleware for every different interface I will have?

Comment: Yes, that or make it generic all the way through.

Comment: What would you do?

Comment: That's really hard to say without knowing what you're doing, but my gut says if you're in this situation, middleware isn't the best approach. Middleware works in situations like an HTTP server where every handler is identical.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says it all, for a type to implement an interface its methods must *exactly match* the methods the interface defines.

Sadly, this means that your system won't work as designed. You will either need to use `interface{}` and assert to the actual type at the end point, or you will need a separate interface (and logger function) for each type.

Comment: What you are saying makes sense I'm just trying to avoid writing logger functions which will effectively be the same code (in my head) thanks for answering :)